# Creation dialog authentication while integrating RTC with Enovia

Tags: integration, rtc

I'm trying to integrate Rational Team Concert to Enovia using OSLC (developed an adapter). Stuck at a step where we need to link Enovia CR to RTC workitem. How to make creation/selection dialog window store the workitem ID and the login credentials so that once I click OK, it creates the required CR in Enovia. Currently, our design forces user to fill the username and the workitem id manually in the creation dialog form to make the system understand that X user wants to create abc CR in Enovia and link to Y workitem ID.

Comment: It is not clear here. From which application you are getting a dialog? Enovia or RTC? Please also include steps/link to the instruction how you are integrating.